# I'm trying to set class but keep getting the error on line 41 the "num_rows line" the error is "Trying to get property of non-object in line 41"

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?
class Db {
  private $connection;
  public  function __construct($option = null){
    if  ($option != null){
      $host  = $option['host'];
      $user  = $option['user'];
      $pass  = $option['pass'];
      $name  = $option['name'];

    }else {

      global $config;
      $host = $config['db']['host'];
      $user = $config['db']['user'];
      $pass = $config['db']['pass'];
 $name = $config['db']['name'];
 }
    $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
    if ($this->connection()->connect_error){
      echo("Connection failed: " .$this->connection->connect_error);
      exit;
    }

    $this->connection->query("SET NAMES ''utf8");
  }
  public function first($sql) {
   $records = $this->query($sql);
    if ($records == null){
      return null;
    }
    return $records[0];
  }

  public function  query($sql){
    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
    $records = array();

     if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        return null;
      }
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $records[] = $row;
      }
    return $records;
  }
  public function connection(){
    return $this->connection;
  }
  public function close(){
    $this->connection()->close();
  }
}
```

Comment: `$sql` is undefined in your code!!

Comment: Lol @Saty I was just gunna ask what `$sql` is. Cause there won't be anything to get an array from if it's undefined. :P

Comment: @Saty @PXgamer I think he is passing `$sql` to the method `query`. I also think the problem is $result  is equal to FALSE. Try var_dump($result) after your first line in the `query` method

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php  Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE. You can't access a property of `FALSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of the `mysqli::query` function is mixed so it depends on the `$sql` query you are sending.

If the query is something like `"CREATE TABLE myTable like anotherTable;"` the return of the query is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. On the other hand if it is really a `SELECT` query, if the operation is not successful you should expect `FALSE` otherwise you have a `$result` object.

so it is better check the type of `$result` before performing operations. I suggest add some checking in your codes like follows:

```
public function  query($sql){
    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
    $records = array();
    if($result === FALSE)
       return FALSE;

    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
       return null;
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanx for hellping

Comment: @farzadking you are welcome, please mark this as accepted answer so the question can be closed